# Controller does not load in component - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directory structure

```
--- js/app.js
------- components
----------- header
-------------- headerComponent.html
-------------- headerComponent.js
-------------- headerController.js
```

in index.html, i have this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html en="us" ng-app="app">

<head>
    <title>Jogo da Memória - DB1</title>
    <!-- bootsrap css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <!-- components -->
    <script src="js/components/header/headerComponent.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeCtrl as $ctrl">
        <h1>{{$ctrl.message}} </h1>
        <header></header>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

js/app.js

```
    (function() {
       var app = angular.module('app', []);
       app.controller('HomeCtrl', function() {});
    })();
```

component/header/headerComponent.js

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app');

    app.component('header', {
        templateUrl: '/js/components/header/headerComponent.html',
        controller: 'headerController'
    });
})();
```

component/header/headerController.js

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('headerController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.titulo = "teste";
   }])
```

component/header/headercomponent.html

```
<h1>{{titulo}}</h1>
```

The problem is that the variable "titulo" is not rendered.
I would not like to use in the component file the controller: function () {} structure. And i have this error: ***Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]*** I would call the external controller. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a more detailed error to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining your module twice, the second time in `component/header/headerController.js`.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

This should change to:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
```

It also doesn't look like `component/header/headerController.js` is included in your `index.html` via script tag.